# How to programmatically delete all conditional formatting on a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-conditionalformatting

I tried combining two examples from https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting

1. Read all conditional formats.
2. Delete them.

Deletion requires the index to delete, but this is not returned in the read API response. I tried assuming that the index of the returned formats in the array was appropriate, but this encountered an error "no conditional format at index" in the middle of the operation, before they were all deleted.

Here is a copy of the sheet I am trying to clear: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y0tsEcka-1gziimesE74IhPFqGkUO985eZNoVQ9y0BU/edit#gid=0

Comment: I was able to _mostly_ work around this by trying to delete each rule individually and ignoring errors, but that still left some formats in the sheet.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue, documentation on updating/deleting isn't clear in comparison to reading. @wescpy might know

Comment: To quickly update in case anyone else reads this, I ended up doing the same as above. Deleting each rule 1 at a time (using the index of 0) seems to work (as each update updates the overall index and there is always a 0 indexed conditional.... maybe?)

Comment: I believe this to be a bug in the Google Sheets API. If you have N conditional format rules, the batchUpdate request only lets you delete (N-1)/2, rounded down, of the rules. I've created an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118196634).

Answer (score 3):

How about this solution? In this solution, you problem can be solved by 2 times of API requests.

### 1. Retrieve all conditional formats from a sheet on Spreadsheet.

`sheets.spreadsheets.get` is used for this situation.

#### Request :

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheet ID ###?ranges=### sheet name ###&fields=sheets%2FconditionalFormats%2Franges%2FsheetId
```

Please input `### spreadsheet ID ###` and `### sheet name ###`.

#### Response :

This response retrieves the number of conditional formats. This is used for deleting conditional formats.

```
{"sheets": [{"conditionalFormats": [
  {"ranges": [{"sheetId": #####}]},
  {"ranges": [{"sheetId": #####}]}
]}]}
```

### 2. Delete all conditional formats.

`sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate` is used for this situation.

#### Request :

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheet ID ###:batchUpdate
```

#### Request body :

Here, `index` means the number of conditional formats retrieved by above `GET` method. For example, when there are 2 conditional formats in the sheet, the length of `requests` is 2. The following `requests[0]` means `sheets.conditionalFormats[0]` as shown above.

```
{"requests": [
  {"deleteConditionalFormatRule": {"sheetId": #####, "index": 0}},
  {"deleteConditionalFormatRule": {"sheetId": #####, "index": 1}}
]}
```

Please input `### spreadsheet ID ###` and `sheetId`.

### Note :

- In order to use above APIs, you can retrieve access token.
- Because to delete all conditional formats on a sheet is the aim, the information which is retrieved from spreadsheet is the necessity minimum.

### References :

- [sheets.spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Xavier Shay I'm sorry I couldn't help. For example, how about trying to delete conditional formats using "Try this API" of [https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)? You can do that by importing spreadsheetId and Request body.

Comment: Batch API doesn't necessarily help, it just groups together other API calls and this case there only appears to be https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deleteconditionalformatrulerequest

Comment: if you have a bunch of rules this won't work because gsheets resets the 0 based index as you delete so at some point your code will error out.

Comment: @grantr Thank you for your comment. About `if you have a bunch of rules this won't work because gsheets resets the 0 based index as you delete so at some point your code will error out.`, in order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide a detailed flow for correctly replicating it? Because I cannot understand `some point`. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to confirm `some point`.

Comment: @grantr Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, if you can use Google Apps Script, in the current stage, when the method `clearConditionalFormatRules` of Class Sheet released on April 11, 2018 is used, all conditional format rules can be removed. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/docs/release-notes#April_11_2018) This method was not existing on Dec 17, 2017  posted this answer. The sample script is `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(sheet => sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules())`. But, if this was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the previous answers and comments and hopefully save someone else some time, this is what I did to remove all conditional formats in a given sheet.

```
def delete_conditional_format_rules(spread_sheet_id, sheet_id)
  reqs = []
  sheet_info = JSON.parse(google.get_spreadsheet(spread_sheet_id).to_json)
  sheet_info['sheets'].each do |info|
    if info['properties']['sheetId'] == sheet_id && info['conditionalFormats']
      info['conditionalFormats'].each do |i| 
        reqs.push(
          delete_conditional_format_rule: {
            index: 0,
            sheet_id: sheet_id
          }
        )
      end
    end
  end
  body = { requests: reqs }
  sheets.spreadsheets.batch_update_spreadsheet(spread_sheet_id, body)
end
```

After getting the spreadsheet information from sheets.spreadsheets.get, I looped through each sheet. After finding the sheet that I want to edit by comparing it to what I passed through the method, I check to see if it has any conditional formats (to null proof it). Then for each array element of conditionalFormats I add a request object to the final array I pass in the body of the call and delete at index 0.

It's probably a little clunky, but I got it to do what I needed it to. Hopefully this helps.